# Test-NetConnection does not always execute ping test

Tags: powershell

In researching, there appears to be variable behavior of the Test-NetConnection PowerShell command, in which, the following command will sometimes execute a Ping Test, and other times, skip over the Ping test. This seems to be the standard of what I'm able to produce on my computer at this moment.

```
C:\Windows\system32> Test-NetConnection www.google.com -port 443
ComputerName     : www.google.com
RemoteAddress    : 142.250.189.228
RemotePort       : 443
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet 4
SourceAddress    : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
TcpTestSucceeded : True
```

However, on some computers, and in some instances, this will yield the following result. This seems to be the standard that I find in screenshots across the internet (https://woshub.com/checking-tcp-port-response-using-powershell/)

```
C:\Windows\system32> Test-NetConnection www.google.com -port 443
ComputerName          : www.google.com
RemoteAddress         : 142.250.189.228
RemotePort            : 443
InterfaceAlias        : Ethernet 4
SourceAddress         : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
PingSucceeded         : True
PingReplyDetauls (RRT): 27ms
TcpTestSucceeded      : True
```

In all cases where the TcpTestSucceeded = false, TNC always yields a PingSucceeded = true/false; But in cases where TcpTestSucceeded = true, TNC only sometimes yields a PingSucceeded.

Can anyone point me in a direction that indicates when TNC chooses to execute an ICMP test in situations where the TCP Port test succeeds?

Comment: On Windows Powershell (5.1) it will skip it if and only if it has done a successful TCP test, the source code is pretty explicit on that so I'm guessing this is platform dependent ? You can check the source by doing `Get-Command Test-NetConnection | select -exp Definition`, line 492. (edit: looks to be the case on 7.3 too but I don't have a machine to test it on 6.0 or 3.0).